# Exception when adding SWRLAPI to manipulate swrl rules in java

Tags: ontology, owl-api, swrlapi

I have a problem when i want to add SWRLAPI or SWRL with Drools API.
I added SWRLAPI, SWRLAPI with Drools and OWLAPI dependencies with maven. 
It seems there is a problem with SWRLAPIFactory.createSWRLRuleEngine(o); 
Here is my Main class

```
    OWLOntologyManager m = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    File file = new File("OoEI.owl");
    OWLOntology o = m.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
     // Create a SWRL rule engine using the SWRLAPI  
    SWRLRuleEngine ruleEngine = SWRLAPIFactory.createSWRLRuleEngine(o);
    PelletReasoner reasoner = com.clarkparsia.pellet.owlapiv3.PelletReasonerFactory.getInstance().createReasoner( o );
```

and  here is my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>OWLAPITest</groupId>
<artifactId>OWLAPITest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.owlapi/owlapi-distribution -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.ansell.pellet/pellet-owlapiv3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ansell.pellet</groupId>
        <artifactId>pellet-owlapiv3</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/edu.stanford.swrl/swrlapi-drools-engine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.swrl</groupId>
        <artifactId>swrlapi-drools-engine</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.swrl</groupId>
        <artifactId>swrlapi</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>






</dependencies>
```

I get this Exception :

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.swrlapi.exceptions.SWRLRuleEngineException: Error creating rule engine Drools. Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError. Message: org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager.getIRIMappers()Lorg/semanticweb/owlapi/util/PriorityCollection;
    at org.swrlapi.factory.DefaultSWRLRuleAndQueryEngineFactory.createSWRLRuleEngine(DefaultSWRLRuleAndQueryEngineFactory.java:73)
    at org.swrlapi.factory.DefaultSWRLRuleAndQueryEngineFactory.createSWRLRuleEngine(DefaultSWRLRuleAndQueryEngineFactory.java:43)
    at org.swrlapi.factory.SWRLAPIFactory.createSWRLRuleEngine(SWRLAPIFactory.java:39)
    at OWLAPITest.main(OWLAPITest.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager.getIRIMappers()Lorg/semanticweb/owlapi/util/PriorityCollection;
    at org.swrlapi.factory.DefaultSWRLAPIOWLOntology.addSWRLAPIOntologies(DefaultSWRLAPIOWLOntology.java:1740)
    at org.swrlapi.factory.DefaultSWRLAPIOWLOntology.<init>(DefaultSWRLAPIOWLOntology.java:161)
    at org.swrlapi.factory.SWRLAPIInternalFactory.createSWRLAPIOntology(SWRLAPIInternalFactory.java:248)
    at org.swrlapi.factory.DefaultSWRLRuleAndQueryEngineFactory.createSWRLRuleEngine(DefaultSWRLRuleAndQueryEngineFactory.java:55)
    ... 3 more
```

Is there a solution ? 
Thanks you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two owlapi versions on the class path, one from pellet and one explicit in your dependencies. Make sure there's only one version at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

So for everyone who have the problem, here is the fix :

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ansell.pellet</groupId>
        <artifactId>pellet-owlapiv3</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6-ansell</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.github.ansell.owlapi</groupId>
                <artifactId>owlapi-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.github.ansell.owlapi</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>owlapi-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.github.ansell.owlapi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>owlapi-parsers</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

or there’s a fork of Pellet using the OWL API v4 here: https://github.com/ignazio1977/pellet.

There's a fork of Pellet using OWLAPI 5 here: https://github.com/Galigator/openllet